# LDAPS and LDAP signing and LDAP channel binding based support in Java Web Application

Tags: java, ldap

Starting from this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirement-for-windows

At the moment a my java 8 web application use a simple bind autentication over LDAP. I need to adeguate my web application to LDAPS with LDAP signing and LDAP channel binding based.
I don't understand if "LDAP signing and LDAP channel binding based" is part of LDAPS protocol or not and if these features have some impacts on the client side.

At the moment the ldap connection is established using jndi (Authenticating to the LDAP by Using the JNDI in this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html )

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
    "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

// Authenticate as S. User and password "mysecret"
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=S. User, ou=NewHires, o=JNDITutorial");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "mysecret");

// Create the initial context
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

...
```

How I can modify the code to support LDAPS and  "LDAP signing and LDAP channel binding based" connection ?